# ActiveRecord where statement either NOT IN (?), or doesn't exist

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a rails Recruiting app, I'm making the query below to select out all potential users that would be a good fit for a particular job

```
  # Job Model
  def potentials
    User.includes(:source, :heat, :applications, common_app: [:cities, :industries]) 
      .where('cities.id IN (?)', self.city_ids)
      .where('industries.id IN (?)', self.industry_ids)
      .where('applications.id NOT IN (?)', self.applications.map(&:id))
      .order('common_apps.progress DESC')
  end
```

The problem is with

```
.where('applications.id NOT IN (?)', self.applications.map(&:id))
```

I'm doing this to make sure I don't get users who have already applied to a job

However, If I write it this way, The query excludes all users who did not apply to any job, and therefore don't have an applications.id

How would I do this, so that in the where query, the statement allows for users who have no applications?

Comment: What value does aplication_id has when the user hasnt applied to any job? 0, blank?

Comment: Hey Oscar, the user doesn't have an application_id. It's more like application is the join model between user and job. I.e user has_many :jobs through: :applications, and job has_many :applicants, through: :applications

Comment: Can you try replacing `self.applications.map(&:id)` with `self.applications.pluck(:id).presence || [-1]`?

Comment: Hey Mr. Yoshiji, no luck with it. I might have made the question a bit too ambiguous. What I'm worried about is not the application count on the job model, but rather on the user model. I.e self in this case is referring to a job, but the thing that gives us the problem is 'applications.id', since in some cases the user may not have an application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
.where("not exists(select * 
       from applications ap 
       where ap.user_id=users.id 
       and ap.job_id=?)", self.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, figured out a fix, but doesn't answer the original question.

Instead of using applications.id in my where clause, I used users.id, which for sure exists in all users.

```
  def potentials
    User.includes(:source, :heat, :applications, common_app: [:cities, :industries]) 
      .where('cities.id IN (?)', self.city_ids)
      .where('industries.id IN (?)', self.industry_ids)
      .where('users.id NOT IN (?)', self.users.map(&:id))
      .order('common_apps.progress DESC')
  end
```

Comment: Do a .to_sql and play with the full SQL query on an app like Sequel Pro, sometimes its easier to spot and error directly in the raw SQL.